# difference between Class.forName("Something") and Class.forName("Something").newInstance();

Tags: java

What is the difference between `Class.forName("Something");` and `Class.forName("Something").newInstance();` Please clarify me.

Comment: The difference lies in the invocation of `newInstance()` obviously. So why don’t you look at the documentation of that method for finding out what it does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Class.forName("Somthing");
```

just loads the class in memory

```
Class.forName("Somthing").newInstance();
```

loads the class in memory and creates an instance of the class represented by the loaded `Class`.

Comment: super , short and precise

Comment: @Juned Ahsan and why we need simply load the class. can  you explain

Comment: @subash to initialize some resource at the class loading time i.e inside static blocks of a class.

Answer (score 2):

1 : if you are interested only in the static block of the class , the loading the class only would do , and would execute static blocks
then all you need is

```
Class.forName("Somthing");
```

2 : if you are interested in loading the class , execute its static bloacks and also want to access its its non static part , then you need an instance
and then you need

```
Class.forName("Somthing").newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName simply loads the class and the newInstance method invokes a new object

```
Class myclass = Class.forName("someClass"); // Load the class
someClass obj = (someClass) myclass.newInstance(); // someClass obj = new someClass()
```